# Create objects and add instances to them (Java)

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to create an object (LineItem), and then create variables of that object. I want to create a 'cookie' that has a price, a name, and a quantity assigned to it. My problem begins at `cookie.price = 5`, my IDE tells me that 'package cookie does not exist.' I am very confused. It gives me the same error whether or not I declare cookie outside of the LineItem class.

```
public static void main(){

  public class LineItem{

  int price;
  String foodName;
  int quantity;

  LineItem cookie = new LineItem();

  cookie.price = 5;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please read a java tutorial...[Start with this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you cannot directly write the executable statements in class.Only variables declaration is allowed outside the method/blocks/constructor
You need to move the code  `cookie.price = 5;` into a method/constructor/block.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a method. You have not got a main method and your program cant start this way. No research done. Use proper syntax and learn the basics. To refer to the class use the this keyword. You shall not create an instance of the class again in the same class. Instead of using this.variable you can refer to the variable straightforward if it is in the same class declared outside of any methods

Comment: Sorry, I do have a main method, I just didn't include it in the post. I didn't think it was relevant to the question, but I'll add it to the post. Sorry for the confusion.